# How to check dynamic generated class from outside function?

Tags: jquery

These are two functions in jquery..
I add some **class** to **(".cards")** in first function (**slected**) and from the second function, i just want to check the length of that newlly added class and do some stuff.. but its not working....

```
clickHandlers = function(){
    $(".cards").on('click', function(){
        $(this).html('<p>' + $(this).data('cardValue') + '<p>').addClass('slected');
        checkMatch();
    });
}

checkMatch = function(){
        if($('.selected').length === 2){
            $('.selected').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: problem with `$('.selected').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });`  your `removeClass` on which you are accessing. :D

Comment: Define "not working".  What *is* it doing?

Comment: use `$('.cards p').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass('selected'); });`

Comment: David second function is not working at all.. its not removing the selected class.... when i generated 2 selected classes by clicking the cards

Comment: Parth Trivedi .... i tried your code .. but its not working

Comment: @AkshayKumar: This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  You can place breakpoints in your code and step through it, line by line, as it executes.  This will allow you to examine runtime values and runtime behavior.  Because "it's not working" is not a meaningful description of a problem.

Comment: ok thanks David..... I will do that..

Comment: @David have you check spelling of `addClass('slected');` it should be `addClass('selected');`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi no need for an `each` to do that .. `$('.cards p').removeClass('selected')` does same thing

Comment: I am so sorry  .... It was full my mistake.... in first function i write the selected spelling wrong.... I am so silly...and  Sorry for wasting your time guys..... and Thanks for all support.... :)  specially @David Thank you for your debug idea....

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are correct

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: It looks like your comment to me was intended for the OP...

Comment: @AkshayKumar do not need to use `each`

Comment: @David sorry it is for O.P

Comment: ok @ParthTrivedi    Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not do `self` removing `element`

```
$('.selected').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                //if selector removed then how your loops works
            });
```

instead do

```
$('.cards p').removeClass('selected');
```

Also check for spelling of `selected`.